# Any option available to load content inside iFrame faster?

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe, angular-universal

I've a typical use case where i need to load content in a iFrame on my home page.

As user experience point of view, i see my Angular App renders in 2 sec & i see content inside iframe take around 3 more seconds which is a very bad user experience

**Options Evaluated:**

- server side rendering via angular universal but I hope this case is irrelevant to SSR
- Trying to show loader but all content in the Home page loads and user seeing loader in particular block it's very bad

Is there any way we can don't let the browser do the heavy job or better way to load content faster. Appreciate your views

Comment: is the iFrame part of  your home component?

Comment: yes that's right

Comment: One way to improve is by taking the iFrame out from the angular template. Currently, the iFrame operations will only start once the main angular app is booted.

Comment: interesting idea Charlie, I've few thoughts after seeing your suggestion, would like understand your view in detail how to proceed

Answer (score 0):

are both parent and iFrame angular apps? if so, you should not use iFrame but an Angular Library instead.

if the iFrame content isn't angular, there isn't much you can do I guess...
To improve the UX you can render a loading spinner over the iFrame and listen for the "load" event and then remove the spinner.

If the iFrame is not in your HomePage but on a secondary page, you could load the iFrame in the HomePage but hide it, and then when you need to display it you can just place it in the right spot and show it to the user instantly.

Comment: it's an angular app. even the content inside iframe we're loading in build on angular(diff app'n) but there are limitations to make it available as a package.

Comment: the wise decision would be to make a package or use a monorepo. I know this probably means a big refactoring and a lot of work, but honestly it's stupid to load an Angular iFrame in another Angular app